# Load contents on scrolling the listview without interrupting the listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar

I am developing an application on Listview. My app should look like this:
It should show 10 elements at first time when i scroll the listview at the 10th position it should start loading next 10 items and so on. While loading next 10 items i should interact with the previous items of listview. I don't want progress dialog to appear while loading. I have done everything but facing a problem at the time of loading data of listview. When listview start loading of items my listview hangs. It neither goes upward nor downward, if i scroll fast it shows me force close dialog.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem i added code plz check it out

Answer (score 0):

Too complex to understand your Code.

but here are the tips which will help you.

- In your adapter their should be a method like this

  ```
  public void setList(List<YouCoustemClass> list) {
                  if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                      items.clear();
                      items.addAll(list);
                      notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
              }
  ```

  - Your `OnScroll` method will be like this

  int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

  ```
                      if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && (loadingMore)) {
                           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                      }
                      if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore))`
  ```

here a extra `check` is added, as if you start a download do not start it again and again. make is `true` in your `AsyncTask's onPreExecute` and make it `false` in `onPostExecute`.

- Now when your download completes then add new data in your previous list, not side by side..using method `setList`. This is the cause of the crash you are facing on `Scroll`. You are adding data in the List but not calling the `notifyDataSetChanged();`
- And one thing more your firsd call is on UI Thread..? also move that request in `Thread`